# Passing data with segue

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

Im trying to pass data from a textfield in ViewController2 to a label in ViewController. It do not seem to work and i get no errors. What am i missing in my Segue?

ViewController2.h

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *HomeTeam;

}
```

ViewController2.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeTeam"];
        NSString *homeTeamText = HomeTeam.text; 
        ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.HomeTeamString = homeTeamText;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *HomeTeamLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *HomeTeamString;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize HomeTeamString, HomeTeamLabel;
```

Comment: Use `NSLog` to print the values of `homeTeamText` and `vc` in your method.

Comment: Is the label properly connected to the reference `HomeTeamLabel` in IB/Storyboard?

Comment: How confident are you that the segue id is really `"HomeTeam"`?

Comment: Do you have the write segue name?  Your code could be confusing with the abundance of "HomeTeam" and the fact that "HomeTeam" is apparently used both as a TextField name and a Segue Identifier.

Comment: There is nothting wrong with using the same expression for a property name and as value for a segue id. However, properties should be start with a lower case (as attributes and local variables too).

Comment: There's not technically anything wrong with it.  It's just better to be more descriptive with your variable names.  For example, I prefix all of my segues with the word segue.  And I might prefix text fields with txt.  So I'd have `txtHomeTeam` and `segueHomeTeam` -- it just makes it more readable.

Comment: Segue id is HomeTeam. I have checked.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what is happening?  Is the segue happening at all?  How are you calling the segue?  Is it hooked directly to a button, or from vc to vc and called some other way?  Does the `HomeTeam` text field have text in it?  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Maybe its because the `NSString` property is weak and will be released immediately after the segue. Try to set it to `strong`. Normally you should always set your properties to strong if you create any in the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `if`.  Unless you've copied and pasted wrong...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeTeam"]) {
        NSString *homeTeamText = HomeTeam.text; 
        ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.HomeTeamString = homeTeamText;
    }
}
```

`[segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeTeam"]` returns a `BOOL` that lets you know whether or not this is the segue that's being performed.

Even if this isn't actually causing a problem (in this example), you should be doing this anyway.  I will update this answer as more information is given.

---

Also, be aware that in this particular code, you're setting an `NSString` property on the destination view controller.  Not a label...

Assuming everything on the storyboard is correct, be sure to add the following to your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method:

```
HomeTeamLabel.text = HomeTeamString;
```

---

And for good measure, you may need to change `HomeTeamString` from `weak` to `strong`.

**EDIT: After some researching...** it seems that the `HomeTeamString` property in your destination view controller MUST be `strong` as opposed to `weak`.  Leaving it as `weak` allows it to be released as soon as the `prepareForSegue` method ends (it doesn't have an owner between `prepareForSegue` ending and `viewDidLoad` in the destination view starting).  Changing it to `strong` will fix the problem ensuring it will only be released if the destination view controller is released.

Comment: @user3033493 I've added some to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that, you set the identifier of the segue in storyboard.[image]

In your case the identifier will be `HomeTeam`.

Comment: Identifier is HomeTeam, but style is modal. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No.  Style doesn't make a difference.